# In the Entity Framework, how to change by code the database connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mysql-connector

I need to change my code because I have the connection string in the web.config. I am calling from a project. I don't want to use app.config. I need to make centralized in web.config.

How can I change or open by code the connection of entity framework? Main project is mvc 5 using framework 4.6.1.

I am using a MySQL database.

I am using this code to change the database:

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Connection.ChangeDatabase(conn);
```

And my connection string is:

```
<add name="conn" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Max Pool Size=1000;MinimumPoolSize=5;ConnectionReset=true;ConnectionLifeTime=0;user id=xxx;port=3306;password=xxx;SSL Mode=none;persistsecurityinfo=True;AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=true;Convert Zero Datetime=True;database=xxx&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: The question is unclear. `app.config` is the equivalent of `web.config` for desktop applications. You can already pass the name of the connection string to the DbContext constructor

Comment: The connection string is a string and you can modify like any other string.

Comment: What you ask is already described in the docs [Use Code First with connection string in app.config/web.config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/connection-strings#use-code-first-with-connection-string-in-appconfigwebconfig-file)

Comment: Giving your application permissions to edit its configuration file seems .... unwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just most easy what I thought. I had to put this code:

```
 base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString)
```

connectionstring from configurationmanager get it from web.config instead of app.config

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for `UseMySQL`. Change the string that is passed to that method (it is the connection string).